# Git cloned laravel 5.2 project won't migrate

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I clone a project from git.
After i run command:
- *composer dump-autoload*
- *composer updated*

File composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

File evn

> APP_ENV=local
>   APP_DEBUG=true APP_KEY=SomeRandomString
>   APP_URL=http://localhost
>
> DB_CONNECTION=mysql
>   DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 DB_PORT=3306
>   DB_DATABASE=wicker_master
>   DB_USERNAME=root
>   DB_PASSWORD=root
>
> CACHE_DRIVER=file
>   SESSION_DRIVER=file
>   QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
>
> REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
>   REDIS_PASSWORD=null
>   REDIS_PORT=6379
>
> MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
>   MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
>   MAIL_PORT=2525
>   MAIL_USERNAME=null
>   MAIL_PASSWORD=null
>   MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Error:

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize


  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                              
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'wicker_master.about_us' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `about_us`)  



  [PDOException]                                                                                    
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'wicker_master.about_us' doesn't exist  


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

Comment: It seems like the project you copied tries to access a table in the postUpdate method. You can check that in your composer.json. For a quick fix remove the responsible line, then run composer update + php artisan migrate, then re-insert the line.

Comment: I removed it, but it isn't working.

Comment: I think it execute the last file migrate not run all file migrate

Comment: What is the error after removing it? Provide your composer.json - also ensure to remove the composer.lock. Show us your .env structure but please anonymise it.

Comment: Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'wicker_master.about_us' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `about_us`).
I add more file .evn and composer.json

Comment: I check custom provider run before migrate. when i comment code in provider, php artisan migrate is working. How config provider run after migrate

Comment: what is the result of "php artisan migrate"

Comment: when I fix code in file custom provider, "php artisan migrate" run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have same db name created as in .env file ?
For example if you have written

`DB_DATABASE=laravel`

make sure you have create database named `laravel`first

Comment: I created db name in file .env

Comment: For example if you have written `DB_DATABASE=laravel` make sure you have create database named laravel first.

Comment: It seems that you don't have database created that you have named in .env fille

Comment: I created Database and edit name database in file .env.

Comment: Share the link of git project you cloned